# Is tf.depth_to_space equivalent to phase shift upsampling?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a super-resolution model in Tensorflow. I have been using the following code

```
def _phase_shift(I, r):
# Helper function with main phase shift operation
bsize, a, b, c = I.get_shape().as_list()
X = tf.reshape(I, (bsize, a, b, r, r))
X = tf.transpose(X, (0, 1, 2, 4, 3))  # bsize, a, b, 1, 1
X = tf.split(1, a, X)  # a, [bsize, b, r, r]
X = tf.concat(2, [tf.squeeze(x) for x in X])  # bsize, b, a*r, r
X = tf.split(1, b, X)  # b, [bsize, a*r, r]
X = tf.concat(2, [tf.squeeze(x) for x in X])  # bsize, a*r, b*r
return tf.reshape(X, (bsize, a*r, b*r, 1))

def PS(X, r, color=False):
  # Main OP that you can arbitrarily use in you tensorflow code
  if color:
    Xc = tf.split(3, 3, X)
    X = tf.concat(3, [_phase_shift(x, r) for x in Xc])
  else:
    X = _phase_shift(X, r)
  return X
```

from https://github.com/tetrachrome/subpixel for upsampling. However, due to the fact that the second argument for tf.split has to be invariant, I decided to use tf.depth_to_space in place of the above code. I am wondering if tf.depth_to_space and the above code do the exact same thing.